# Spree on ruby on rails (No products / Admin panel issue)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, spree, solidus

I am not able to get into the admin panel in Spree & Solidus 
I've tried both gems and failed miserably. They also don't return the
default home page with ROR t-shirts instead my frontend says *no products*

I have pictures with my issue being displayed:
[Solidus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1KMC.png)
[No product or default set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkbp.png)

Answer (score 2):

When you've finished setting up according to the instructions you should have finished with:

`rake db:seed`

This will put the default values in there and will show you the admin user and password that were created.  The admin panel is available at `/admin`

You'll also want to run

`rake spree_sample:load`

This will load the example products and orders into the store.

Comment: But what if we don't want sample products? What if we just want our own products? My current problem is that I can't create inventory and I cant set StockLocation because I can't figure out how to set default country. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808099/how-to-set-default-country-in-solidus-ecommerce

Comment: Solution was quickly found. A case of talk to the duck. Follow the link in previous comment for answer.