# How to set default country in Solidus Ecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, solidus

First off, I'm trying to create (inventory) stock for my Product Variants. Not too sure but it appears that I need to create a Stock Location.

Next, I'm trying to set Stock Location. However, I get the following error message:

```
"You must create a default country before creating a stock location."
```

How do I create default country? The only logical place that might be in the schema is: **spree_stores.cart_tax_country_iso.**

However, using the admin panel does not show country ISO's in the drop down list under shipping. I also tried manually inserting from Rails Console. I tried 2 letter ISO and 3 letter ISO. Nothing seems to work.

**How do I set the default country code in Solidus?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating my App, I created my own seed because when I followed the Getting Started tutorial, I either had no seed or had sample data I didn't want.

The solution to the question is that I copied the country.rb seed from from the solidus_core gem: gems/solidus_core-3.0.1/db/default/spree/country.rb

I copied it into my seed file and commented out previous seed and raked.